# Is there a concept of growth priority in javafx?

Tags: css, javafx, flexbox

How does JavaFX renderer decides which component grows when pref sizes sum of 2 components is lower than the overall scene size ?
Is there any way to decide which component should grow first and how more than the other component as flexbox does in regular css ?
here is a css code that describes what i want to do in my javafx app :

```css
.my-container {
   display: flex;
   width: 1400px;
}

.my-component-1 {
    /*pref width is 800*/
   flex: 2;
}

.my-component-2 {
   /*pref width is 300*/
   flex: 1;

}
```

for example, in the above case, component 1 will grow up to 1000px and component 2 up to 400px.
what is the javafx equivalent to the flex property ?

Comment: This is exactly the functionality of the various [layout panes](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/package-summary.html). Most layout pane classes have mechanisms for configuring how extra space in the pane is allocated to different child nodes.

Comment: I am using a GridPane for such Tasks..You can specify the percentage distribution of the rows and columns.

Comment: in my case I'm using a BorderPane but it has no properties like GridPane to property set growth priority

Comment: Correct: in a `BorderPane` the additional space is allocated to the `center`. The `top` and `bottom` get the full width of the container, and their preferred height; the `left` and `right` get the full height of the container, minus the height of the `left` and `right`, and their preferred width. If that isn't what you need, choose a different layout pane (probably `GridPane`, `HBox`, or `VBox`, depending on which regions of the border pane you are using).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small example how a `GridPane` layout with "Percent Width" works:

Preview:
[image: stage width: 1100]
Controller Class:

```
package sample;

import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class WidthController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Pane
            redPane,
            bluePane;
    @FXML
    private Label
            stageWidthLabel,
            redPaneWidthLabel,
            bluePaneWidthLabel;

    private DoubleProperty
            stageWidth = new SimpleDoubleProperty(),
            redPaneWidth = new SimpleDoubleProperty(),
            bluePaneWidth = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        stageWidthLabel.textProperty().bind(stageWidth.asString());
        redPaneWidthLabel.textProperty().bind(redPaneWidth.asString());
        bluePaneWidthLabel.textProperty().bind(bluePaneWidth.asString());
        redPaneWidth.bind(redPane.widthProperty());
        bluePaneWidth.bind(bluePane.widthProperty());
    }

    public void setStage(Stage stage) {
        stageWidth.bind(stage.widthProperty());
    }
}
```

FXML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<GridPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="1100.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.WidthController">
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" percentWidth="72.73" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" percentWidth="27.27" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints vgrow="NEVER" />
  </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <Pane fx:id="bluePane" style="-fx-background-color: blue;" />
      <Pane fx:id="redPane" style="-fx-background-color: red;" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
      <GridPane hgap="3.0" vgap="3.0" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
         <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints fillWidth="false" halignment="RIGHT" hgrow="NEVER" />
            <ColumnConstraints fillWidth="false" halignment="LEFT" hgrow="NEVER" minWidth="10.0" />
         </columnConstraints>
         <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints fillHeight="false" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="NEVER" />
            <RowConstraints fillHeight="false" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="NEVER" />
            <RowConstraints fillHeight="false" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="NEVER" />
            <RowConstraints fillHeight="false" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="NEVER" />
         </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Label text="Width information" underline="true" />
            <Label text="Stage:" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label text="Blue Pane:" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <Label text="Red Pane:" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <Label fx:id="stageWidthLabel" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label fx:id="bluePaneWidthLabel" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <Label fx:id="redPaneWidthLabel" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
         </padding>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

Application Class:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("width.fxml"));
        Parent root = null;
        try {
            root = loader.load();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (root == null) return;
        WidthController controller = loader.getController();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
        controller.setStage(primaryStage);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```